# How to wrap_content with tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tabs

I would like to know how I can change my tablayout to wrap_content?
At the moment every tab takes up one third of the screenspace, but I want one of the tabs to be smaller than the others or just so that it wraps the content of the tabs.

This is my code:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
          actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

             ActionBar.Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
                tabA.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_settings);
              actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
             actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

            tabA.setText("");
         tabA.setTabListener(new com.example.MainActivity.TabListener<Tab1>(this, "Tab1", Tab1.class));
         actionBar.addTab(tabA);





          Tab tabB = actionBar.newTab();
        tabB.setText("Tab2");
         tabB.setTabListener(new com.example.MainActivity.TabListener<Tab2>(this, "Tab2", Tab2.class));
          actionBar.addTab(tabB);

            Tab tabC = actionBar.newTab();
enter code here
            tabC.setText("Tab3");

         tabC.setTabListener(new com.example.MainActivity.TabListener<Tab3>(this, "Tab3", Tab3.class));
         actionBar.addTab(tabC);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
              int savedIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("SAVED_INDEX");
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedIndex);
       }
```

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom Views for tabs with preconfigured layout params

```
ActionBar.Tab.setCustomView
```